# Is it possible to reduce the number of capacitors in the ft232h recommended configuration?

Tags: capacitor, ftdi

I'm trying to design a board as small as possible. I'm trying to minimize the number of components I need.

My design is based off the self powered configuration of the FT232H chip. I've decided to use ceramic instead of tantalum caps(I'm aware of the repercussions).

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232H.pdf

So my question is, could I reduce the amount of caps safely(why)?

Comment: Are you basing off of figure 2.6 in the datasheet?  You can leave out the components marked "N.F." (no-fit)

Comment: @markrages Assuming you meant 6.2 on page 52...

Comment: yes, so I meant.\

Comment: Without understanding your supply tolerance, the chip supply requirements, ripple, crossover frequency of the supply, temperature, dynamic load currents, etc., you are just guessing and you need to solve empirically. But then again, one test case in a lab at room temperature doesn't mean it'll work reliability.  There is in fact a way to analyze what you really need before you design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust me, a datasheet configuration doesn't guarantee good operation. You may find that you'll need more, not less, capacitors in various places - the layout is said to contribute the equivalent of half of your BOM in unexpected parasitics and interactions.

I would suggest not deviating from the initial configuration on your first pass. You can always test removing some caps and if the performance is acceptable, leave them not populated in the final product.

Also, avoiding tantalum where practical is a good approach. Ceramics are safer if the board is handled and built properly (mechanical stress is their only real weakness).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Madmanguruman - layout and caps on a lot of digital stuff can cause hours of heartache. So you want to design as small as possible - If it's a four layer board then consider mounting some components underneath chips on the reverse side - I'm assuming "small as possible" means chiefly board dimensions first and foremost. If you are also worried also about board height issues then ignore my recommendation.

Comment: It'd be a smaller module that you could mount on another board. So I wouldn't put anything on the bottom. Yes, it would be board dimensions that I'd want to reduce.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The only caps I can see that you can safely reduce would the the three 0.1uf caps between VIIO and Gnd. They are in parallel, and having three of the same value would mean they are filtering out the same frequencies if any. A single 0.3uf cap would just as easily replace all three.</strike>

The other caps, all coming from the internally regulated 3.3v rail, are after an inductor, and are different values, so they would be there to smooth out the regulated line down to the needed voltages. You may be able to skip the 0.1uf minor decoupling cap, but not the 4.7uf.

As @Relianthe pointed out, the layout has pins grouped by function. The VCCIO pins are not together, so each should have it's own decoupling cap.

Comment: Those are for each VCCIO pin, which are quite far apart from one another.

Comment: Hmm, the recommended layout makes them look like they are in parallel. That's what happens when they group like pins together ha. Okay thank you @Relianthe